# Python __reverse__ magic method

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, reverse

I'm trying this piece of code expecting that it returns a string of text after reversing with `[::-1]` but it is not working.

```
class meh:
  def __init__(self, bla):
    self.bla = bla
  def __reversed__(self):
    return "Reversing!!!! %s" % self.bla[::-1]

a = meh("Reversed successfully!!!!")
print a[::-1]
```

How to properly call the `__reverse__` function?
Example: `__gt__` is called with a `> 25`, what calls `__reverse__`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`[::-1]` is a **slice**. [`object.__reversed__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) is instead used by the [`reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), and is only applicable to *sequences* (objects that provide both a `__len__` and a `__getitem__` method).

If you don't supply `__reversed__`, the function uses those `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods to access indices in reverse. `__reversed__` must itself return an iterator:

```
class Reversable(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.seq)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.seq[item]

    def __reversed__(self):
        for elem in 'Reversing: ' + self.seq[::-1]:
            yield elem
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Reversable(object):
...     def __init__(self, seq):
...         self.seq = seq
...     def __len__(self):
...         return len(self.seq)
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return self.seq[item]
...     def __reversed__(self):
...         for elem in 'Reversing: ' + self.seq[::-1]:
...             yield elem
... 
>>> r = Reversable('Foo bar baz!')
>>> list(r)
['F', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'z', '!']
>>> list(reversed(r))
['R', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'n', 'g', ':', ' ', '!', 'z', 'a', 'b', ' ', 'r', 'a', 'b', ' ', 'o', 'o', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists do have [`reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) method since of Python 2.4

```
r= list("asdfasdf")
r.reverse()
print(r)
print(''.join(r))
```

---

```
['f', 'd', 's', 'a', 'f', 'd', 's', 'a']
fdsafdsa
```